# AuthenticationError when accessing Azure BlobServiceClient in Java app

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am new in Azure. I am trying to create simple Java app to connect and then download data from Blob Container
I started from creating creating
Here is code fragment

```
String sasToken = "my blob sas token key";
        
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
        .endpoint("my blob sas URL")
        .sasToken(sasToken)
        .buildClient();
        
try {
    BlobServiceProperties props = this.blobServiceClient.getProperties();
    PagedIterable<BlobContainerItem> items =  this.blobServiceClient.listBlobContainers();
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("APP exception: "+ex.getMessage());
}
```

After running this code fragment - getting exception :

```
If you are using a StorageSharedKeyCredential, and the server returned an error message that says 'Signature did not match', you can compare the string to sign with the one generated by the SDK. To log the string to sign, pass in the context key value pair 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign': true to the appropriate method call.
If you are using a SAS token, and the server returned an error message that says 'Signature did not match', 
you can compare the string to sign with the one generated by the SDK. 
To log the string to sign, pass in the context key value pair 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign': true to the appropriate generateSas method call.
Please remember to disable 'Azure-Storage-Log-String-To-Sign' before going to production as this string can potentially contain PII.
Status code 403, "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:cd0a04bd-f01e-0061-159d-ceb31d000000
Time:2023-08-14T10:55:53.7449600Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The specified signed resource is not allowed for the this resource level</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>"
```

Blob SAS token key and Blob SAS Url were generated with settings as attached screenshot
Is there something missing / wrong in the code above ?
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: How does your Blob SAS URL look like?

Comment: https://<myaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/dev?sp=racwdl&st=2023-08-14T11:33:15Z&se=2023-08-14T19:33:15Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=rUXvP4e6hYRm7qHJGpTqGyzaVqRP%2F1KZYFpsgy4pZzU%3D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because you have created a [`Service SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-service-sas) and trying to perform an operation (`blobServiceClient.getProperties()`) at the account level using that SAS. With a Service SAS you are only allowed to perform operation on either the blob (if the SAS is created for a specific blob) or the blob container and blobs inside that container (if the SAS is created for a specific blob container which is what you are doing).

To fix this issue, you will need to create an [`Account SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas) and use that SAS URL (which will be something like `https://account.blob.core.windows.net?sas-token`). You can create an Account SAS in Azure Portal by navigating to the storage account and then selecting Shared Access Signature from the menu on the left hand side.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav Mantri. Yes , I generated SAS for Blob container. But  : in order to access this container - should I first create BlobServiceClient  ? Thanks

Comment: With this SAS, you can directly create `BlobContainerClient`. However I noticed that you want to list blob containers and that will only be possible with an Account SAS.

Comment: Is connection string passed to BlobContainerClientBuilder same as SAS Url ?

Comment: Try this one instead: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.blobcontainerclientbuilder?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-storage-blob-blobcontainerclientbuilder-credential(com-azure-core-credential-azuresascredential)

Comment: Actually I needed to to download blob data , list of containers - called only for test client. After creating directly BlobContainerClient - it works - thanks